# pandas to_sql when table has constraints and some records violoate constraint

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, optimization, psycopg2

I have a ~1M rows pandas DataFrame, `df`, that I'd like to store in a Postgresql (9.3.1) database.  It seems logical to use `df.to_sql` on large batches:

```
df.to_sql('names',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='append',chunksize=10000)
```

> IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) insert or update on table "names_h" violates foreign key constraint "name_h_fk"
>   DETAIL:  Key (name)=(HXD13) is not present in table "valid_names".

Raised because there is a constraint on the `names` table which I'm trying to `INSERT` -- and <100 of the records in `df` violate this constraint.

To solve my problem I grabbed all the `valid_name` records from `valid_names`:

```
df_valid = pd.read_sql("SELECT valid_name FROM valid_names",cnxn)
```

and filtered out the ***bad names*** from my original `df`.

```
final_df = df.loc[df['name'].isin(df_valid.valid_name.tolist())]
```

Now, `final_df` executes fine and populated my table.

```
final_df.to_sql('names',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='append',chunksize=10000)
```

So, is there a more efficient method to load records into a database when some (in my case a small fraction) of your records violate a table constraint?  I've thought about a vectorized try except, or df.apply and iterating one by one, but I'm not familiar with what `to_sql` does under the hood.  Thank You.

Comment: I think your approach is very reasonable. Under the hood, pandas just executes a (or multiple) `INSERT` statements. And you have eg for postgresql a [`ON CONFLICT` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) for inserts, but as far as I can see this is not generally supported by SQLAlchemy (the library that pandas uses to make its code database-flavor agnostic)